# calculate monthly and twelve last date in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table sales

```
Activity | Sector | dateSale | Amount
CREATE TABLE sales
(Activity nvarchar(100) ,
Sector    nvarchar(100) ,
dateSale  date ,
Amount as float )
```

I need to calculate monthly and twelve last month date in the same row:
Expected result for example:

```
Activity | Sector | AmountMonth | AmountLTD
```

I tried to calculate amount in a month

```
declare @date as date,
set @date ='17-11-2020'----- I should to calculate amount in the previous month of the date parameter: all october for the same year 
SELECT SUM(Amount)
      ,Activity
      ,Sector 
FROM sales
WHERE [dateSale] between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date)-1, 0)
                     and DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @date)-1, -1)
group by Activity
        ,Sector
```

I tried to calculate amount in a LTD bbut it's wrong, I need to correct it:

```
 declare @date as date,
    set @date ='17-11-2020'----- I should to calculate amount in the ltd of the date parameter Ineed to calculate from november 2019 to october 2020
    SELECT SUM(Amount)
          ,Activity
          ,Sector 
    FROM sales
    WHERE [dateSale] between DateAdd(DAY,-Day(@Date)+1,@Date)
                         and DateAdd(MONTH,-13,@DateR2)
    group by Activity
            ,Sector
```

How to do the calulation in the same row a it's expected please? Is there any anothor simple way to do the calulation?

Comment: Could you please add some test data and the desired output from that test data into your question, ideally as a `create table` statement?

Comment: Thanks.  Ideally your table script would come with some test data and the desired output based on that data that I mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the amount for each month as well as the trailing 12 months, then you need to calculate the sums separately.  It isn't clear from your question exactly how you want the output, but hopefully the following will help.  It calculates the sum of each month in the inner query and appends the trailing 12 in the outer query.

```
SELECT s.Activity, s.Sector, s.StartOfMonth, s.AmountMonth, SUM(salesLtd.Amount) [AmountLTD]
FROM (
    SELECT Activity, Sector, SUM(Amount) [AmountMonth], StartOfMonth
    FROM sales 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, dateSale), 0) [StartOfMonth]) [forStart]
    GROUP BY Activity, Sector, StartOfMonth
) s
INNER JOIN sales salesLtd ON salesLtd.dateSale <= EOMONTH(s.StartOfMonth) 
    AND salesLtd.dateSale >= DATEADD(year, -1, s.StartOfMonth)
GROUP BY s.Activity, s.Sector, s.StartOfMonth, s.AmountMonth
```

I could've used a CTE to construct the inner query and then use the same CTE in the join in the outer query (presumably to take advantage of already aggregated data), but I suspect it would actually be slower.